# time series modeling and criteria thereof

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

**Give criteria for aiding in the choice of a best time series model when two or more such models are available. What is, arguably, the most important criterion?**

I am not sure if RMSE is enough, or SBCC?

Comment: This question does not provide a lot of detail. However, in general, information criteria or similar techniques can be used to compare models.

Comment: @Marc, for time series modeling, in general, what would be the most important criteria when comparing across to other time series models? Please state your assumptions and justify. Thanks